# How to debug the cause for SQLiteError(11): database corruption

Tags: database, sqlite, debugging, corruption

I have been tasked with finding the cause for 2 repeated lines we find in about 5% our logs in our Beta environment (this app is not in prod yet). They are as follow:

> SQLite error (11): database corruption at line 55472 of [cf538e2783]
>
> SQLite error (11): database corruption at line 55514 of [cf538e2783]

That's it. No other info is available, and it's always those two lines. They are being logged by `System.Data.SQLiteLog.LogEventHandler` and the Log System is `Trace`.

Interestingly, it appears that the database continues to function and usage of our application continues without any apparent problems.

So my question is: **Is there actually an issue, and, if so, how do you go about identifying it?**

In my research on the issue I have to believe that there is a legitimate problem here. According to [www.sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) corruption in SQLite should be rather rare. A false corruption report can be caused due to database shrinkage (8.1), but I don't think that's the case here. I must assume at this point that the report is correct and the database is actually corrupt.

However, how could the database continue to function normally for hours of use if it is, in fact, corrupted?

Many sites give [solutions](http://froebe.net/blog/2015/05/27/error-sqlite-database-is-malformed-solved/) on how to fix this issue (by reverting to a backup, or otherwise recreating the database), but I need to find what's causing this issue.

I have tried installing DB Browser for SQLite and browsing the database, but all seems well and there doesn't seem to be a way to "browse" to the lines that are reportedly corrupt. (There must be a way to do so, though, right? Why would they give line numbers if it's impossible to know what those line numbers are?)

Are there operations or areas that are likely culprits in this circumstance that I can investigate? How do I identify the lines that are being referenced in the error messages?

Comment: Show the output of [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check). What OS, file system, VM, or NAS are you using in the beta environment?

Comment: @CL. Unfortunately, I have not been able to replicate the issue on my machine to run the PRAGMA integrity_check, and for a number of reasons I won't get into here, I can't access databases on the machines that are running in the beta environment. They are all running versions of Windows that are 8.1 or later.

Comment: What file system, VM, or NAS are you using in the beta environment?

Comment: Or are you using multiple threads?

Comment: So after some work I was able to access a DB which encountered this error. Executing PRAGMA integrity_check returned "ok".

Each computer has it's own local DB -- this is a WPF, native desktop app -- so I'm not sure if your inquiries regarding a NAS, file system, etc. apply. I'm not sure how to answer them in any case.

Comment: I have been able to replicate several times now (every time I have caught the error) that a PRAGMA integrity_check returns "ok". This has occurred across several different machines.